# 3D FFT of field in a cube

Tags: matlab, fft

I got simulation data from a 3D field distribution in a cube over a timeperiod t. So I got exactly 61 3d matrices of field data in a timeframe [0,T]. For further calculations, I need the harmonics of the signal and therefore apply 3d fft.

The dimensions of the cube are Lx, Ly, Lz respectively. Since the data from the simulation is not evenly spread across the volume, I first interpolated it on a 3D grid with size 128x128x128.
Since the data is pretty much independent in z-direction, it is split in 2 3D matrices (P and Q) for the x- and y-componentent of each gridpoint's vector.

First of all I setup the meshgrids on which I wanna evaluate the 3d fft:

```
Lx = 0.03; %30mm width
Ly = 0.005; %5mm length
Lz = 0.090; %90mm thick
samples_x = 64; samples_y = samples_x; samples_z = samples_x; %choose equal samples in x,y,z
[x_mag,y_mag,z_mag] = meshgrid(linspace(0,Lx,samples_x),linspace(0,Ly,samples_y),linspace(0,Lz,samples_z));

load P_Q_meas.mat %load the P and Q matrix and time-vector t 

%P,Q are now interpolated on the x,y,z grid (not included here)
```

The interpolation seems to work just fine, since I can compare it with the plots from the simulation. The vector `t` contains the timesteps on which the 3d data was recoreded.
Now I try to 3d fft the P and Q matrix with matlab's `fftn`-commnad:

```
P_loss = zeros(size(t)); %empty vector for loss-over-time data

for timestep = 1:length(t) %loop over all timesteps
   Zx = fftn(P);
   Zy = fftn(Q);
   a = abs(Zx./((samples_x*samples_y*samples_z)));   % Magnitude with normalization
   b = abs(Zy./((samples_x*samples_y*samples_z)));   % Magnitude with normalization
   theta_x =  unwrap(angle(Zx)); % Phase
   theta_y =  unwrap(angle(Zy)); % Phase
   
   p5 = zeros(size(a)); %empty matrix to store following calc. data

   for m=1:size(a,1)
        for n=1:size(a,2)
            for k=1:size(a,3)
               p5(m,n,k) = (-a(m,n,k))*b(m,n,k)*(m*pi/Lx)*(n*pi/Ly)*...
                    Lx*Ly*Lz*cos(theta_x(m,n,k)-theta_y(m,n,k));

               P_loss(timestep) = P_loss(timestep) + p5(m,n,k);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The simulation, where I got the `P` and `Q` matrices from, also calculates `P_loss`, so my script should result in similar values. But sadly I am off by a factor of rougly 3e7. I assume the error to be somewhere in the 3d fft here and hope someone of you can try to help me out with this!
I checked the Parseval theorem to ensure proper normalization with

```
time3D = sum(sum(sum(abs(P).^2)));
freq3D = sum(sum(sum(abs(Zx).^2)./((samples_x*samples_y*samples_z))));
```

for each timestep and at least that seems to be correct.
I assume I mixed something up with the meshgrids or the time domain setup, but I cant spot the mistake since roughly 2 weeks now and I tried a lot. Interestingly, the shape of my `P_loss` and the one from the simulation seem to be similar, but need to be scaled by a factor. Additionally, the `P_loss` amplitude of each sample changes with the number of `samples_x,samples_y,samples_z` I choose, e.g. the peak values increses by a factor of roughly 6, which in my opinion should not happen.

I am looking forward to your input and appreaciate your help,
Thank you in advance!